# How can I fix my haskell code to count the first person points in rock paper scissors?

Tags: haskell

I would like to count how many times the first player win a game. Can anybody help me to fix it ?

```
data RPS = Rock | Paper | Scissors deriving (Eq) 

beats :: RPS -> RPS
beats rps = case rps of 
    Rock -> Scissors
    Paper -> Rock
    Scissors -> Paper


firstBeats :: [RPS] -> [RPS] -> Int
firstBeats (a:ax) (b:bx)  
 | a==Rock && b==Scissors = 1 + (firstBeats ax) : (firstBeats bx)
 | a==Scissors && b==Paper = 1 + (firstBeats ax) : (firstBeats bx)
 | a==Paper && b==Rock = 1+ (firstBeats ax) : (firstBeats bx)
 | otherwise = (a: firstBeats ax) + (b : firstBeats bx)

Examples:
firstBeats [Rock] [Paper]    == 0
firstBeats [Rock] [Scissors] == 1
firstBeats [Paper, Scissors] [Rock, Paper] == 2
firstBeats [Paper, Scissors, Paper] [Rock, Paper, Scissors] == 2
firstBeats (replicate 20 Paper) (replicate 20 Rock) == 20
```

Comment: What is the problem currently?

Comment: You don't actually tell us what the problem is, but at a glance there are multiple issues in your `firstBeats` function. Why do you expect using `:` (a list constructor) to give you back an `Int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `firstBeats` takes two parameters, so you should pass the tails of the two lists. Furthermore you should cover the case where one of the two lists, or both are empty, so:

```
firstBeats :: [RPS] -> [RPS] -> Int
firstBeats (a:ax) (b:bx)  
 | a == Rock && b == Scissors = 1 + firstBeats ax bx
 | a == Scissors && b == Paper = 1 + firstBeats ax bx
 | a == Paper && b == Rock = 1 + firstBeats ax bx
 | otherwise = firstBeats ax bx
firstBeats _ _ = 0
```

But this is not elegant and requires a lot of repetition. You can define a function that checks if the first item has beaten the second with:

```
hasBeaten :: RPS -> RPS -> Bool
hasBeaten Rock Scissors = True
hasBeaten Scissors Paper = True
hasBeaten Paper Rock = True
hasBeaten _ _ = False
```

Then you can just implement this as:

```
firstBeats :: [RPS] -> [RPS] -> Int
firstBeats (a:as) (b:bs)
    | hasBeaten a b = 1 + firstBeats ax bx
    | otherwise = firstBeats ax bx
firstBeats _ _ = 0
```

But the modeling also is not very nice. One would expect to work with a list of 2-tuples of `RPS`s, such that it is impossible to pass two lists whith a different number of items. Then it is:

```
firstBeats :: [(RPS, RPS)] -> Int
firstBeats = length . filter (uncurry hasBeaten)
```

Comment: Great answer. There is already a `beats` function, so I think one could alternately write your `| hasBeaten a b` guard as `| a == beats b` without introducing a new function.